# Magento 2: Add loading effect on remove product from the mini cart

Tags: magento2, cart, remove, loading

I want to add loading effect before ajax call of remove product from the mini cart.

Right now when I remove the product from the cart, It takes 4-5 seconds to delete but user cannot identify whether the process is going on or not.

I tried to find JS file for the responsible code but not able to find it.

Does anyone have an idea which JS file contains code to call AJAX to remove the product from the cart?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check below file

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

it has events on click, can find something like `_removeItem`

If you are using any custom theme, it may be there under `Magento_Checkout` modules directory

Comment: Ok let me check

Comment: How did you fix this? i dont get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I override below file in my custom theme

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/sidebar.js

In place of `_removeitem` I put in `_ajax` method.

I show loading effect in `beforeSend` of that method and hide in `complete`